# Is this space of continous functions a Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I started new in funcional analysis and have a question about Banach Spaces. I'm supposed to show that

$X = C^0([0,1]) = {f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f 
  \quad \text{continous} }  $

is a Banach Space with the Supremum Norm

$||f||_{C^0} = ||f||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

I've shown Banach Space with limited functions, but I'm not sure how to work here, because $f$ can diverge.

Comment: How can $f$ diverge? Also, why do so mention linear functions in the title?

Comment: Show that every Cauchy sequence of functions has a limit in X

Comment: Every continuous function on a compact interval,  $[0,1]$ in your case, is bounded. So there is no problem with "divergent'' functions.